# Securing folders in source control

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-security

I would like to know how I can secure an Area (folder within project) - i.e. give access to external consultants for reading and writing.

But I do not want them to be able to access other folders within that Project.

I know how to assign access to the folder (defined Area), but I'm not sure how I can safely remove their rights on the Project without cutting off their access to the folder (Area).

Any help appreicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends wither you mean Area Paths or Source Control folders.

!!Source Control

In TFVC you can open the web access  and go to the code tab. There you can right click on any folder and select permissions. Her you can use any fine grain you like and control inheritance.

In Git you can  only control permission ls at the Repository  and Branch level.

!!Work Item Tracking

If you open the web access and go to the administration section (cog on top right) and then the Area Path tab you can control the permission in the same way you can with  source code. If you have VSTS or TFS 2015 Update 2 you can also control inheritance.

!!Real solution

However any sort  of compartmentalisation comes with significant overhead of  managing it. If you are a defence company or bank and there is that one folder that you  don't want externals to have access then  it's easy. Remove inheritance for that folder and only allow specific access.

Anything more and you run into complexity and friction for users. Ultimately you should trust everyone you give access to your Team Project. Ifnuoy  don'ttrust them, then  don'tgive them access...

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Administer Server page and create a new TFS user group.

[image]

Add the users to the TFS user group.

Go to the Code screen, right click the folder and choose Security.  Next add the TFS User Group you create and give them the rights you want:

[image]